# Block display using wildcard, non-greedy

Tags: blocks

I have a block that I have configured to display "Only on the listed pages"

```
commerce_store/store/*
```

The problem is, it displays not only on the view link, which I want it to, but on the edit and other menu tabs

```
commerce_store/store/1        <-- good
commerce_store/store/1/edit   <-- bad
commerce_store/store/1/sales  <-- bad
```

I've tried switching to PHP code, but this doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever. I've even changed the code to `var_dump($path); exit;` and it doesn't exit.

**Edit**: This code works, just enclose it in `<?php` and `?>`

```
$path = current_path();
$url_parts = explode('/', $path);
if( $url_parts[0] == 'commerce_store' && $url_parts[1] == 'store' && count($url_parts) == 3 ) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can use `arg(x)` where `x` is the position in the path starting from 0, so you could do something like this as well:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) . arg(1) == 'commerce_storestore' && !arg(3)) {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

You could also use [drupal_match_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7) like so:

```
<?php
if (drupal_match_path(current_path(), "commerce_store/store/*") && !arg(3)) {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

Cheers,

Comment: I like the `drupal_match_path` solution, it seems the cleanest, though you were missing 1 argument which I added in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, dumb question. I didn't notice that `<?php` and `?>` are required. Funky how they're required in some places and not in others. I guess I'll leave the question up in case the PHP code helps anyone else.