# Allow block display on child nodes but not grandchildren

Tags: blocks

In a block configuration, I would like to show the block on
/programs/* but not on programs/* /*

I have seen a number of questions similar to mine.
[Block display using wildcard, non-greedy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96608/block-display-using-wildcard-non-greedy/96612#96612) for example.

The recommendation from the above link to use drupal_match_path() makes the most sense to me.  I have implemented the following,

```
    <?php
if (drupal_match_path(current_path(), "programs/*") && !arg(2)) {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

expecting the block to appear on /projects/name but not on /projects/name/grandchild-node.  The block doesn't appear anywhere. Just to test the system, I tried this:

```
    <?php
if (drupal_match_path(current_path(), "programs/*") {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

and still the block doesn't show.
I'm certain that I'm doing something wrong that is very basic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Are you sure current_path() is returning the alias?  cause I don't think match_path takes that in to consideration at all.

$path = current_path();
$path_alias = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$path);